# How to disable or remove web pages from my web site

Tags: html, web, redirect, iis, asp.net-webpages

I want to block or delete some pages on my website. Maybe these pages can be used again in the future, so I don't want to delete them directly and I want to prevent users from accessing these pages via URL or my website. I searched a bit but couldn't find much detail.

Could you suggest me what I can do about it?

Comment: Can you remove them from your routes?

Comment: Does your hosting provider offer to protect some directories with a password? You could use this.

Comment: If you ever use a source code control system like Git, you know changes can be recovered any time you like. So please simply delete them and commit. There is no need to resort to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script element to the header for your HTML and have the script be,

```
location.href = "homepage.location/";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to delete them directly and I want to prevent users from
> accessing these pages via URL or my website

If you want to set it in IIS, Request filtering is a great choice for you. You can add any URL in it to prevent others access it and don't need to delete physical file.

Now I can access it.

[image]

Add a deny sequence.
[image]

Now I cannot access.(Same URL)
[image]